# Wiring for Light switch in sump pump room

Tags: electrical

The builder of my townhome allocated a "room" underneath my stairs to the basement and dug out the sump pump pit. There is a small door leading into the room and they drywalled all the wall and ceiling.

I have wired a dedicated 20AMP circuit (single outlet) for the pump with a 20AMP GFCI breaker.

My questions are:

1. Is a light required for this "room" / space? My understanding is YES as it is a space which may require service (pump).
2. Can the light be run off the circuit for the pump? Or does the pump need to be on its own circuit and I need to find another source for the light?
3. And if I need to provide another source for the light I assume as long as I do not put the light over the sump pit, the source providing power to the light does not need to be GFCI?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you use a battery-powered light? Surely you won't be using the light very often... That saves the wiring of a new circuit and the concerns about a GFCI.

Comment: Interesting.  I like the idea.  I thought I read for a room which has serviceable equipment a light is required and I thought this meant "permanent".

Comment: As per 210.70(C) as I am reading it "...dwellings were required to have a lighting outlet if these spaces contained equipment that required servicing such as HVAC units."

"In the 2017 NEC, utility rooms, and basements, must have at least one lighting outlet containing a switch or controlled by a wall switch, located where these spaces are used for storage or contain equipment requiring servicing. At least one point of control must be at the usual point of entry to these spaces. The lighting outlet itself must be at or near the equipment requiring servicing."

Answer (score 2):

1. NEC 210.70 **Lighting Outlets Required**  210.70(3) **Storage or Equipment Spaces** ...control shall be at the usual point of entry to these spaces...The lighting outlet shall be at or near the equipment..
2. A sump isn't specified as needing a dedicated circuit, but circuit ampacity, location of disconnecting means, and manufacturer instructions would come into play for the exact pump installed. If the sump is considered NEC 210.23(2) **Utilization Equipment Fastened in Place** it can't exceed 50% of the branch circuit rating of a shared circuit. Otherwise if not fastened in place then a cord connected plug is limited by NEMA and NEC 210.21(B)(2) to 12A on 15A plug and 16 on a 20A so circuit capacity to add lighting could be assumed adequate. AHJ interpretation could come into play.
3. If your installation or circuit ampacity requires a dedicated circuit for the sump, then Section 210.8 which specifies most of the locations GFCI protect is needed applies to *receptacles* not lighting *outlets* (at least through NEC 2017).